# How to find text between 2 characters with multiple occurrences?

Tags: javascript

Given the below string, what would be the most efficient way to get the file ID? The portion wanted: `XXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxXXX`, which is between `/` and `/view`

The attempt below works, but is it really needed to reverse the string twice?

```js
let = url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pnEX1OXXXXXXu6z9dPV5ZZ5VHqPU--6/view?usp=share_link'

url = reverseString(url)

let id = url.split('weiv/').pop().split('/')[0]
id = reverseString(id)

console.log('URL:' + id)

function reverseString(str) {
  var splitString = str.split("");
  var reverseArray = splitString.reverse();
  var joinArray = reverseArray.join("");
  return joinArray;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem itself: you asked *"what's the most efficient way"*... well, if you're not doing this operation millions of times in a row and if the string doesn't have a humongous size of thousands of characters, in modern computers it really doesn't matter, it will be very fast. In my opinion you should ask what's the easiest way to maintain, or the most readable way for other people to understand it etc.

Comment: is it everything between / and /view? i.e. 1pnEX1OXXXXXXu6z9dPV5ZZ5VHqPU--6 in your example?

Comment: Thanks, @GerardoFurtado! Good point! It will be processed once only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution searches for the "/d/" portion and advances three characters to begin a `string.slice`, continuing until the next occurence of `/`. Provided /d/ is always before the id portion, this should be reliable.

```js
const url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pnEX1OXXXXXXu6z9dPV5ZZ5VHqPU--6/view?usp=share_link';

const id = url.slice(url.indexOf("/d/")+3, url.indexOf("/",url.indexOf("/d/")+3 ));

console.log(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve this with a simple regex.

```
const url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pnEX1OXXXXXXu6z9dPV5ZZ5VHqPU--6/view?usp=share_link';
const m = url.match(/^.*?\/.\/(.*?)\/view.*$/);
console.log(m[1])
```

Comment: you can avoid counting forward slashes. `/(?<=\/)[^\/]+(?=\/view)/`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regex seems to be another little universe. Lots to learn.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `substring` to get the value between `/d/` and `/view`

```js
let = url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pnEX1OXXXXXXu6z9dPV5ZZ5VHqPU--6/view?usp=share_link'

const fileId = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/d/") + 3, url.lastIndexOf("/view"));

console.log(fileId)
```

Comment: we have very similar solutions, I think I was typing at the same time.

Comment: and they both rely on `/d/` which hasn't been confirmed as stable.

Comment: @pilchard, I've checked a couple of sampled files and ```/d/``` is always there! I think I'll use this. Thanks guys!